# Использование LinkedHashMap Java

Tags: java, jdbc, servlet

Добрый день!
Отличительной чертой этого контейнера является то, что с помощью поля **accessOrder** можно установить способ обхода мапа. В инете пишут, что необходимость в этом возникает 1 раз на 10 случаев. Говорят, что он используется в кэшировании данных. Мне как раз необходимо кэшировать запросы пользователей, работа проходит в сервлете, который делает запросы к БД. Пользователь вводит название авто, цену, год и степень убитости, сервлет ищет в БД. Сервер работает под нагрузкой.

Вопрос : как реализовать кэширование запросов.

Comment: И в чем, собственно, вопрос?

Comment: Что именно вам непонятно? На первый взгляд у вас есть вся необходимая информация для реализации кэша. Ключ - запрос, кэшируемое значение - реузльтат выборки из БД. Кроме того, кэш должен быть доступен из множества экземпляров сервлета, а значит, доступ к нему нужно синхронизировать.

Comment: @a_gura, видимо проблема с алгоритмом (критериями) удаления из кэша.

Т.е. как использовать LinkedHashMap с этой целью (но, это лишь телепатия).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Крутая штука, оказывается этот LinkedHashMap. Не знал что с ним так можно :)

Но ответ гуглится за 1 минуту.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry(java.util.Map.Entry)

Comment: Если ответ есть в доках - дело не должно доходить даже до гугля )))